# VisualStateManager is not supported in a WPF project

Tags: wpf, xaml, visualstatemanager

I'm using `<VisualStateManager>` in my xaml and it returns "VisualStateManger is not supported in a WPF project". I wonder that is it I need to install WPF Toolkit to enable it? Or I need to put a specific xlmns for xaml? By the way, I'm using visual studio 2013 and .NET Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below link:
http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2008/06/10/visual-state

According to the link, VisualStateManager class isn’t in the Silverlight Xaml namespace, so we’ve had to qualify it with a namespace prefix:

```
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
```